# Formatting `nullptr` on out stream as hexadecimal address, instead of `0`

Tags: c++, formatting, cout, nullptr

How can I format a null pointer of any type, preferably including immediate `nullptr`, on out stream so it prints out like `0x000000000000` or even just `0x0` but something resembling an address value instead of a senseless `0` or *terminate* or whatever non-address-like? //`(nil)` or `(null)` I could accept too if not using `printf`.

Comment: Can you use C++20 features?

Comment: A value of zero, when converted to a pointer, gives a null pointer constant.  So outputting a zero does actually make some sense.   If `ptr` is a pointer, you could always do `if (!ptr) std::cout << "0x0"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a pointer formatter, which can do the formatting in whatever way you prefer.

For example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

static auto Fmt(void const* p) -> std::string {
    auto value = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p);
    constexpr auto width = sizeof(p) * 2;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "0x" << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(width) << std::hex << value;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    char const* p = nullptr;
    std::cout << Fmt(p) << "\n";
    p = "Hello";
    std::cout << Fmt(p) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Also, please note that with C++20 [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) exists.

Comment: @Eljay It appears <iostream> and <iomanip> suffice for this solution. If I'm missing the purposes of the other headers please elaborate on them.

Comment: @Multifix • `<cstdint>` for std::uintptr_t. `<string>` for std::string. `<sstream>` for std::stringstream.  `<ios>` for std::hex.

Answer (score 0):

You can just overload << operator for void pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void bar() {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, void *p) {
    return stream << 0 << 'x' << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(p) << std::dec;
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Foo *p = &foo;

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    p = nullptr;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Or add a wrapper which is more flexible, since you can use both approaches, but will require a bit more typing.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void bar() {}
};

struct Pointer_wrapper {
    void *p_;
    explicit Pointer_wrapper(void *p) :p_(p) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Pointer_wrapper& w) {
    return stream << 0 << 'x' << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(w.p_) << std::dec;
}

using pw = Pointer_wrapper;

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Foo *p = &foo;

    std::cout << pw(p) << std::endl;
    p = nullptr;
    std::cout << pw(p) << std::endl;
}
```